# ViewPager - Preview only 1 right page but not the last page

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I setup my `ViewPager` to only show preview of 1 page on the right side using `setPadding` and `pageMargin`:

```
viewpager.setPadding(smallSpace, smallSpace, largeRightPadding, smallSpace)
viewpager.pageMargin = normalSpace
viewpager.offscreenPageLimit = 2
```

`largeRightPadding` is large enough to show my right preview page. My current UI looks like this:

**This is how the first item with right preview looks:**
[image: ViewPager first item]

**If I scroll to the last item, there will be empty space on the right** 
[image: ViewPager last item]

**I want to make it likes this, NO empty space for the last item, instead it will show the preview of the left page**
[image: ViewPager expected]

Thanks in advance

Comment: i just have a little question,why you dont use recyclerview instead

Comment: Hi @shadow , Currently changing the code to `RecyclerView` is quite complex, and I am not sure if it works for this case. I remember 1 time I happen to make the `ViewPager` behave like that but now when I need it I cannot find any solution. Maybe I will try `RecyclerView` if there is `ViewPager` solution

Comment: yes,you should try to set the with of item to 2/3 with of screen ( in onCreateViewHolder) and your recyclerview will work well :D

Comment: Can you try `viewPager. setClipToPadding(false)` and run?

Comment: Hi @Kushal,  I've set `clipToPadding='false'` in the xml already, that's why I can see the preview page on the right